# java --version shows 10 but java 11 is installed

Tags: java, ubuntu-18.04

Previously I had java 8 installed by default. After upgrading java version to 11 it shows `openjdk 10.0.2 2018-07-17`.

I downloaded `jdk-11.0.2_linux-x64_bin.deb` from oracle site and installed it. After that I ran `sudo update-alternatives --config java` to change the version to 11 but after running `java --version` command I get following output:

```
openjdk 10.0.2 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4, mixed mode)
```

output of `javac --version`:

```
javac 10.0.2
```

Comment: check `JAVA_HOME` variable https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java

Comment: Output of `find / -name java` is ?

Comment: Check your `PATH` variable. Delete all java related entries except the one which points to your `JDK-11/bin`. Its a left-over from a previous installation.

Comment: Try `locate java` you probably have all the versions you mention installed.

Comment: Running `sudo` doesn't alter the current environment, though it can alter new ones.

Comment: I changed the path to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/` but it did not fixed the issue.

Comment: @Zabuza I don't think I should delete everything except `jdk 11` because I have a netbeans installation and netbeans requires java 8 to run.

Comment: @PeterLawrey `update-java-alternatives --list` shows all the installed versions.

Comment: Java is backwards comp. Your netbeans will likely work fine with the jdk 11. Your PATH variable should only point to one java installation. More than one also make no sense, since only the first `java.exe` and `javac.exe` are used.

Comment: Interestingly `ls /usr/lib/jvm/` gives me `default-java               java-11-openjdk-amd64  jdk-11.0.2
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64  java-8-oracle`

Comment: Also worth reading in this context: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037646/why-is-openjdk-10-packaged-as-openjdk-11/1037655#1037655 (tldr: it's intended that the version 11 package of Ubuntu contains java 10)

Comment: @Zabuza Thanks for your advice. I deleted java 8 and it screwed up everything. Netbeans is giving some weird outputs.

Comment: That is a clear sign that something in your setup is broken. Having multiple Java on PATH makes no sense. It is completely useless, since only the first one will be used.

Comment: @Zabuza I bet that the installation is fine. I have read the error logs. Some methods and classes were deprecated after java 8 and completely removed in java 11. So, it were those methods and classes which were causing the issue. Anyways, I have fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting confused between openjdk and oracle jdk. You have installed openjdk 11 and hence it shows you version as 10(read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037646/why-is-openjdk-10-packaged-as-openjdk-11/1037655#1037655) answer as suggested by Joachim Rohde). You can update the alternatives and reconfigure it:

Remove openjdk 11:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java"
sudo update-alternatives --remove "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java"

sudo update-alternatives --remove "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac"
sudo update-alternatives --remove "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac"
```

If you wish, you can delete the openjdk folders using:

```
sudo rm -r /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/
sudo rm -r /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/
```

update alternatives install oracle jdk:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.2/bin/java 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.2/bin/javac 1
```

Reconfigure:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Now run the `java --version` and you will get the output as `java 11.0.2`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Its based on past experience, version 1.8 had the same issue. https://novicestuffs.wordpress.com/2017/04/25/how-to-uninstall-java-from-linux/

Comment: Basically, you are asking to replace OpenJDK with OracleJDK. With the licence stuff coming up I would refrain from going to Oracle JDK. But the stmt "You have installed openjdk 11 and hence it shows you version as 10.", really does not makes any sense. That way, I have OpenJDK 8 installed too, then it should show version as 7. May be thats a bug in OpenJDK 11.

Comment: @AbhayDandekar Yes, it does look like a bug. But I don't think that statement is completely wrong.

Comment: May I put a humble request to explain that stmt. Seems a bit confusing :)

Comment: There was a problem with java 8 in the earlier version, see https://novicestuffs.wordpress.com/2017/04/25/how-to-uninstall-java-from-linux/ and I reproduced it with java 11, so the statement is kind of correct. Read the line *Else if you have Openjdk installed then you will get the following result*

Comment: @AbhayDandekar *With the licence stuff coming up I would refrain from going to Oracle JDK*, that's debatable and I think you know that already.